# Font properties for "document.write" not working

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML document includes

```
<font face="helvetica"> (and of course </font> later)
```

This works great and everything is in Helvetica.
However, there is a JavaScript part,

```
if (d > 5) {
    document.write('Message');
}
```

And the text that results from it is not in the desired font.
I tried the methods of applying the style to it but then it doesn't display the JS part at all, how can I make this be displayed in the same font HTML is in?
Is there an HTML tag that can make the whole document be in the same font?

Comment: _Is there an HTML tag that can make the whole document be in the same font?_ By using CSS properly. The `<font>` tag was long-since deprecated.  `body { font-family: helvetica, otherfont, someotherfont; }`

Comment: The problem has NO relation with `font` or `document.write()`. Look this : http://jsfiddle.net/apbbJ/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, stop using `<font>`. It's not the 90s anymore.

The (most probable) reason the dynamic content is not in the font you want is that `document.write()` puts the content outside the tag. Take a look at the generated HTML to confirm this. [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/xPNUa/) shows that the content is styled correctly when the JavaScript is placed inside the tags.

But, as Kolink's answer shows, you should use CSS to style the `<body>` of the document if you want to change the document's default font.

---

Looking at [your example in the comments](http://jsfiddle.net/valkalinic/sE8DS/5), it looks like you're using jQuery - now it should be trivial to avoid `document.write()` (which you should avoid in any case).

Replace the `document.write()` with:

```
$( 'body' ).append( 'Message' );
```

Or, if you want to style the message:

```
$( 'body' ).append( '<div class="message">Message</div>' );
```

and add a CSS rule for the message class (for example `.message { font-weight:bold; }`).

See http://jsfiddle.net/sE8DS/6/.

Comment: thanks but I can't make it like the example does as I have an if that includes JS variables and I can't get that to work inside of the script tag; http://jsfiddle.net/valkalinic/sE8DS/5/

Comment: Thanks so much! But why is the 'Message' shown down there in the fiddle You posted?

Comment: Because if you append something to the document it will be added as the last element.

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
body {font-family: "helvetica", sans-serif;}
```

Done. No need for the ancient `<font>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS, the `font` tag was deprecated ages ago:

```
html {
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
}
```

And also `document.write()` is considered bad practice.

Use this instead:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="helvetica"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#helvetica {
    font-family: 'Helvetica'
}
```

Javascript:

```
var helvetica = document.getElementById("helvetica");

helvetica.innerHTML = "Message";
```